# Percent of if statements with both branches executed based on branch coverage percent?

Tags: math, code-coverage

I was wondering about branch coverage. Is it possible, based on branch coverage, to calculate how the percentage of if-statements that have executed both of their branches?

Comment: How do you have your branch coverage result? And, are you maybe talking about path coverage?

Comment: Hi @deviantfan. No I am not talking about path coverage. I am only interested in branch coverage. I have my branch coverage in percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(...)
{
    A
}
else
{
    B
}
if(...)
{
    C
}
else
{
    D
}
```

Execute two times: AC and AC
50% Branch coverage (like described in your comment), 0% of the if-else´s fully covered.

```
if(...)
{
    if(...)
    {
        A
    }
    else
    {
        B
    }
}
else
{
    if(...)
    {
        C
    }
    else
    {
        D
    }
}
```

Execute two times: AC and AD
50% Branch coverage (2 of 4), but now 33% of the if-else´s fully covered.
...so no, not possible in my opinion.